# Drag and Drop in React on scale container

Tags: css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, resize

I am new to react.I am working on drag and drop.
The draggable components are dragged from one container and dropped on another container,say **container A** .Container A also has zoom in and zoom out property which is achieved through changing the scale.
When dragged from a container A with large scale,the component is in its original size and also it is not with the mouse cursor.
My requirement is that,while dragging from the container with large scale the component should be with cursor.
*How do i achieve it?*
Help would be appreciated.

```
zoomIn = (e) => {
  if(this.state.scale===0.5)
  {
    e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale=1})`

  }
    this.setState({ scale: this.state.scale * 2});
    console.log("zoomin" + ""+ this.state.scale)
    e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale})`
    e.target.style.transformOrigin="-0% -0%"

    out=0  

  }
zoomOut = (e) => {
  this.setState({ scale: this.state.scale / 2});
  if(this.state.scale===1)
  {
    e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale=null})`
    out=1
    this.cood()
  }


  else{
    out=0
  }
   e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale})`
   e.target.style.transformOrigin="-0%,-0%"
   console.log("zoomin" + ""+ this.state.scale)
  }

  dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
    var dragtarget1=document.getElementById("dragtarget1")
    var dragtarget2=document.getElementById("dragtarget2")
    if(event.target.id=="dragtarget1")
    {
     setTimeout(function(){
      dragtarget1.classList.add('hide');
    });

  }
  if(event.target.id=="dragtarget2")
  {
   setTimeout(function(){
    dragtarget2.classList.add('hide');
  });
}
       }
    drop=(event)=> {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
      event.target.appendChild(data);
      data.style.position = "fixed";

      if(this.state.scale>1){
        data.style.left = (event.nativeEvent.offsetX - data.clientWidth / 2)  + "px";
        data.style.top = (event.nativeEvent.offsetY - data.clientHeight / 2) + "px";

      }
      else{
        data.style.left = (event.clientX - data.clientWidth / 2)  + "px";
        data.style.top = (event.clientY - data.clientHeight / 2)  + "px";
        }
      var dragtarget1=document.getElementById("dragtarget1")
      setTimeout(function(){
      dragtarget1.classList.remove('hide');
      });
      var dragtarget2=document.getElementById("dragtarget2")
      setTimeout(function(){
      dragtarget2.classList.remove('hide');
      });

    }
```

Comment: Any code about what you have achieved?

Comment: @keikai Above edited version has the code for the functionality